# What happens to running Web Worker when the browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have some functions which i need to call in web worker so that user will not get affect of it. Lets say the function requires 5 to 10 minutes of time to execute means to finish the task of web worker.

If web worker is running and in middle of that user closes the browser what will happen. I mean function will gets fully executed or it will terminated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875310/what-happens-to-an-html5-web-worker-thread-when-the-tab-is-closed-while-its-run and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084348/what-happens-to-a-web-worker-if-i-close-the-page-that-created-this-web-worker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will terminate the functions...

Answer (score -2):

**Basic opinion about this question:**

```
when you colse the browser all functions can stop and that web worker also terminated.
```